# how to check if ssl exists on a webserver through php?

Tags: php

I have this function in a class:

```
function enable_ssl() {
    if ($_SERVER[HTTPS] != "on") {
        $domain = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/" . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
        header("Location: {$domain}");
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the server doesn't have SSL installed and I have this function initiating the page redirects to a 404 page. I was wondering how I can have this function work only when SSL is installed and working?

Is it possible?

Thanks.

> P.S.: I did some Google research but couldn't find much of anything.

Answer (score 2):

On a *nix server, you could try parsing the output of `netstat -A inet -lnp` for a web server listening on port 443. Kinda clunky.

Better option, I'd say, is to make it a configuration option for the user. Let them tell your app if they've got HTTPS enabled.

Comment: The problem is that if they edit settings through a GUI and they enable SSL, then they will be unable to turn SSL off again because of errors. That means that the software provider is getting a confused support ticket, and the provider has to go in and change that themselves, with website downtime in between.

Answer (score 2):

two ideas

1. Setup a socket connection to port 443 and see if it connects.
2. Read through an apache config file and see if there's anything listening on that port

Answer (score 2):

Extension Loaded!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php

e.g.

```
if(!extension_loaded('openssl'))
{
    throw new Exception('This app needs the Open SSL PHP extension.');
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue. Just because the extension is loaded doesn't mean there's an SSL cert present and turned on for a particular virtualhost.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to connect to the server using [curl](http://us.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php).  However, I would also try to do a config option.  If you use the below, make sure you don't cause an infinite loop.

```
function ignoreHeader($curl, $headerStr)
{
  return strlen($headerStr);
}

$curl = curl_init("https://example.com/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURL_HEADERFUNCTION, 'ignoreHeader');
curl_exec($curl);
$res = curl_errno($curl);

if($res == 0)
{
  $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
  if($info['http_code'] == 200)
  {
    # Supports SSL
    enable_ssl();
  }
}
else
{
  # Doesn't.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use xampp as my development server on my laptop.  I have yet to set up a SSL connection on xampp.  My production server does have SSL enabled and also has a valid cert.

I noticed that $_SERVER['HTTPS'] does not exist on my xampp development server, but does exist on my production server.

I am assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that if $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is not set, SSL is not enabled on the server.

```
<?php

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS')) echo 'SSL Exists'
else echo 'No SSL'

?>
```

Comment: In most cases, $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is only set if the request was made via SSL, testing if it is set will only tell you if the current request was an HTTPS request or not. Unfortunately it won't tell you if it is possible to request the same URI with SSL.

Answer (score 0):

I just use `file_get_contents` to try and open the same file via https and if it was successful, force a redirect...

```
    function IsHttps() 
    { 
        return 
            (!empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && (strtolower($_SERVER["HTTPS"])!=="off")) 
            || ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]==443); 
    }

    if (!IsHttps() && extension_loaded("openssl"))
    {
        $target = "https://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
        ini_set("allow_url_fopen", true);
        if (file_get_contents($target)!==false) 
        { 
            header("Location: https://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["URL"]); 
            die(); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the code below

```
$file ="https://mydomain/index.php";        
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
$DomainName=(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found')?'http://mydomain':'https://mydomain';
```

This basically checks if a file can be found (accessed) via HTTPS.

Comment: Can you format the code properly and add some explanation about why that solves a nine years old problem?

Answer (score -2):

This is how wordpress does it:

```
<?php
function is_ssl() {
if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ) {
return true;
if ( '1' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'] )
return true;
} elseif ( isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) && ( '443' == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) ) {
return true;
}
return false;
}
?>
```

You can use your validation in between 'return true' stuff! Go to:
http://tutes.in/2012/02/13/check-if-ssl-exists-on-a-webserver-through-php/
for explanation and more detailed source code.